# how to combine multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, date, create-table, unpivot

I have the following table below:

Table name: STAT

```
Region   M07  M08 M09 
---------------------
P1       0    1   0    
P2       0    0   0   
P3       2    0   0    
P4       0    0   0     
P5       0    0   0     
P6       0    0   0   
P7       9    0   3
```

I UNPIVOTED the months columns on the TABLE STAT, which contain numerical values.
Obtained Result

```
---------------------
Region   Month  Qty
---------------------
P1      M07    0
P1      M08    1
P1      M09    0
P2      M07    0
P2      M08    0
P2      M09    0
```

The UNPIVOT was done using this code

```
select Region, month, qty FROM
(
    SELECT Region, 'M07' AS month, M07 AS qty from STAT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 'M08' AS month, M08 AS qty from STAT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Region, 'M09' AS month, M09 AS qty from STAT
)x
```

I would now need to add a new column to this unpivoted data set. 
For e.g. a column named "PROFILE". 
I tried writing the code as

```
ALTER TABLE STAT
ADD COLUMN `Profile` CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MI';
```

Then I tried to display the results of the unpivoted dataset and new column added by writing

```
SELECT * from STAT
```

However I am now seeing the new column added to the original dataset, but I cannot see the unpivoted data. I would like to see the unpivoted data and final new column added.
I am assuming I need to write an ALTER table somewhere in the unpivot part of the code. Some help here would be appreciated ?

Comment: Your "UNPIVOT" produced a result set; it did not modify the original STAT  table.  In general, that's true for all SELECT statements; they don't modify the tables they're selecting from.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you that is correct. What do I need to edit in the SELECT part of the code for my unpivot section to make changes to the table ?

Comment: That's probably not the right approach.  Don't mix DDL (data-definition) statements with DML (data manipulation) statements.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you for the note. I will look into this. I am fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually create a new table to store the unpivoted data. This can be achieved by wrapping you query in `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE stat2 AS
SELECT region, 'M07' AS month, M07 AS qty from stat
UNION ALL
SELECT region, 'M08', M08 AS from stat
UNION ALL 
SELECT region, 'M09', M09 AS from stat;
```

Then you can do :

```
ALTER TABLE STAT2
ADD COLUMN `Profile` CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MI';
```

And, of course :

```
SELECT * from STAT2;
```

Comment: that would mean I need a set of code to CREATE TABLE for reading the actual columns in my CSV......and then to CREATE another table like you suggested to store the unpivoted data ? Is there any way to actually combine this to only rite one create table to load the data and then unpivot ?